# Database-side ordering by distance from strings in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm using the Entity Framework to model an existing SQL Server database. For the moment, I only have read access to the database.

I need to order my query by distance, but the lat/long are stored as strings in the database instead of a spatial type like `SqlGeometry`. I'm trying to use `DbGeometry.FromText` on the lat/long within the LINQ query so that I can then call the Distance method on it, but that's not working. I've Googled extensively with no luck.

Here's the code where I've been trying to get it to work:

```
var point = DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(" + latitude + " " + longitude + ")");
var query =  (from a in context.Adjuster
                join ac in context.AdjusterContact on a.AdjusterId equals ac.AdjusterId
                join z in context.ZipCode on ac.ZipCode equals z.Zip
                let p = DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(" + z.Latitude + " " + z.Longitude + ")")
                where (a.Active && !a.IsRecordDeleted)
                orderby p.Distance(point)
                select new AdjusterWithAdjusterContactAndZipCode() { adjuster = a, adjusterContact = ac, zipcode = z })
                //.OrderBy(r => DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(" + r.zipcode.Latitude + " " + r.zipcode.Longitude + ")").Distance(point))
                .Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: maybe you encountered the exception `NotSupportedException` due to EF not recognizing the method `DbGeometry.FromText`? If so the easiest solution may be try playing with `LinqKit`.

Comment: I've gotten that one while working on this, although the current one is "Data type 0xF0 (user-defined type) has an invalid user type specified".

Comment: You can only do that in memory, after getting the unordered results from the database.

Answer (score 0):

try getting the DbGeometry object like this:

```
DbGeometry point = DbGeometry.FromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})",longitude, latitude), 4326);
```